# Swift 5 - Timer not firing

Tags: swift, timer

I have the following,

```
class someViewController : ViewController{
    var timer:Timer? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(fire), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

@objc func fire(){
print("fired")
}
    
}
```

The fire function is never hit and I can't figure out why, what am I missing?

Comment: Nothing is missing what I can see, have you debugged the code?

Comment: Yeah it's definitely hitting the create timer part, gets past that fine and then just doesn't drop into the fire function, so weird.

Comment: not related to your question but you dont need to declare your timer as optional `var timer: Timer = .init()`

Comment: dont forget to call `super.viewDidLoad()`

Comment: I know that's just the state it was in after I was trying everything under the sun. Something weird going on as running it through DispatchQueue.main is fine.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  If so, what did you do?  I am having the same issue as I too have a second view controller and I setup a timer and it never fires.  I have added code that ensures the timer is being run on the main thread, but still no firing of the timer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the issue: the timer needs to be scheduled on main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {  
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: self.BLINK_TIMEOUT, target: self, selector: #selector(self.clearTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}
```

Comment: The timer is being setup in `viewDidLoad` which is always called on the main thread.

Comment: Not sure if you have resolved the issue. You are calling it from viewDidLoad. Hope you have it sorted out.