# Swift 5.5 Timer not firing in segue

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Folks, I have searched and read and I cannot figure out why my timer is not firing in my segue until I have closed the view for the segue and returned to my ViewController view.

So, at the risk of duplication, I am going to post my code and hope someone has some kind of suggestion as to what I can do to figure this out.

I have a game and all my code has primarily been in the ViewController class and I am ready to start breaking it apart into other classes.  So, I am working on a new PlayGameViewController that will replace the methods that relate to game play in my main ViewController class.  The PlayGameViewController is being instantiated and presented via a modal segue after a button is clicked in the ViewController view.

Once the PlayGameViewController is displayed I set up a timer (named timer1 to not be confused with the timer in the ViewController class) by calling a startTimer() method.  I have the updateViewsWithTimer as an `objc func` and it never gets fired until the view for the PlayGameViewController view is closed, via clicking the red dot in the upper left of the PlayViewController view.

I put in print statements to help me debug and I can see that timer1 is, in fact, being instantiated and it is on the main thread, but the updateViewsWithTimer objc func never gets called until I close the PlayGameViewController view.

I found a couple of articles such as [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66064694/swift-5-timer-not-firing) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780888/why-is-this-swift-timer-not-firing) that appear to try to remedy this very issue, but it is not in a segue and their problem doesn't suddenly start to work by closing a view.

Here are my code snippets:

```
import Cocoa
class PlayGameViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate {
    // EDIT: Changed this back to the original I use in my code
    var timer1 = Timer()
    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startTimer1()
    }
    func startTimer1() {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            if timer1.isValid {
                timer1.invalidate()
            }
            print("Preparing to schedule timer1.")
            timer1 = .scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(updateViewsWithTimer1), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            print("timer1 scheduled!")
        }
    }
    // EDIT: Added property timer: to method call as per Leo Dabus in the comments
    @objc func updateViewsWithTimer1(_ timer: Timer) {
        print("updateViewsWithTimer1 fired by timer1.")
    }
}
```

---

Here's the prepare method from my ViewController class if that helps.

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let pvc = segue.destinationController as? PlayGameViewController else { return }
    pvc.view.frame.origin = .zero
}
```

---

Oh, and self is actually pointing to PlayViewController.  I thought maybe that was an issue since I had the same method in ViewController, but that doesn't seem to be it either.

Comment: Not related to your question but there is no need to declare your `timer1` as `lazy`. It doesn't need to access `self` at instantiating time. It also seems that it would never be `nil` therefore `timer1 != nil` will always succeed.

Comment: Roger that.  I've just been throwing darts based on other posts I've read.  Extremely frustrated at this point.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Btw your selector signature should be `@objc func updateViewsWithTimer1(_ timer: Timer)`

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I updated the code.

Comment: No need to declare your timer as optional

Comment: check the updated code. Are you still having trouble with it?

Comment: Yes, it continues to behave the way I wrote about.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997548/2303865. add this after scheduling your timer `RunLoop.main.add(timer1, forMode: .common)`

Comment: Okay, I will have to research this new approach.  I am not familiar with it and I do not know how to implement it.  I will post back once I am successful at implementing it.

Comment: Just add that line of code below the `scheduledTimer` call

Comment: Thank you @LeoDabus!  I just learned something new.  Now I need to go research it some more and make sure I understand why that works.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help.